# improving MySQL write performance

Tags: mysql

I have a giant MySQL database with write intensive workload.

Actually I've created at application level a script that create sql files and CSV with the data, I export this data and load with a batch that use LOAD DATA INFILE syntax because I read that this method is faster than normal sql insert statement.

I know that this is a workaround and this doesn't allow me to replicate the data using statement-based logging because it's unsafe.

There are any suggestion for loading huge and constant bunch of data without degrading performance of MySQL and without using "load data infile" method?

Actual server:

- Percona mysql server 5.6
- 8 SSD disk raid 10
- RAM 128Gb
- Buffer pool: 108Gb.

Comment: If you want replication, then using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to load into a staging table and then inserting from the staging table to the final table might work.

Comment: do you import the data in a empty table ?

Comment: no, i import the data in a production table currently growing. i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried doing all operations in a single transaction?